# How to fill in missing parts of point cloud data in Python

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

[image]

I'm thinking of a program in python that can acquire 3D data.
When converting a depth image to point cloud data, there are inevitably some missing parts.
I think it is possible to convert it to mesh data as it is, but in order to improve the accuracy, it may be necessary to interpolate the missing data.
I thought that it is necessary to interpolate the missing data to improve the accuracy of the conversion.

#### What I don't understand

What kind of algorithm or libraries should I use to interpolate the missing parts of the above image in python?

I have been looking into various literature myself, but I would appreciate it if someone could help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just dropping some findings I had: a. Look into anistropic diffusion and use of graph neural networks to fill this hole. b. Look into how pointcloud is converted into mesh, for example poisson reconstruction allows you to build a complete mesh which can be used to approximately fill hole. Just try poisson reconstruction available in meshlab.

Comment: ````
meshlab: . /src/meshlabplugins/filter_screened_poisson/poisson_utils.h:282: bool MeshDocumentPointStream<Real>::nextPoint(OrientedPoint3D<Real >&, Point3m&) [with Real = float; Point3m = vcg::Point3<float>]: Assertion `nn!=Point3m(0,0,0)' failed.
Abort (core dump)
```
I get the above error and meshlab dumps core.